How do I get Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly to run side-by side so I may utilise the new features of .NET 8?
How do I get Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly to run side-by side so I may utilise the new features of .NET 8?
I have a .NET 8 core application utilising client-side rendering (CSR) using Blazor WebAssembly. It's a none-trivial application using services instantiated by the client (for authentication, uistate, local storage etc.).
I would like to implement a handful of server-side rendered pages (Login pages, and redirection) that do not require the full WebAssembly to load.
The WebAssembly client works, as per MS docs:
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false)" />

and
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Client.Program).Assembly">

To get server side rendering to work, I can implement
<Routes />

and
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Sever.Program).Assembly">

With this configuration, I can render pages server-side, and even render some (trivial) WebAssembly components. However, when doing so, the WebAssembly entry point is no longer invoked (ie WebAssembly.Program() is not executed) and the WebAssembly client is not set up to run correctly. I end up with server errors describing a failure to instantiate client only objects (ie localStorage) for the substantial part.
How do I get Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly to run side-by side so I may utilise the new features of .NET 8?
I expect (hope!) the answer lies in one (or all) of the following

modification of <Routes> such that certain urls reference a different AppAssembly (?!)
modification of endpoints.MapRazorComponents<App>() to identify between WebAssembly parts from Server parts
anything else!(!?)

With many thanks in advance.

If you create a Web App with per page/component option. These demonstrated SSR Home.razor Streaming  Weather.razor and InteractiveWebAssembly Counter.razor

The FluentUI templates for blazor have a slightly different approach particularly in the router component with the per page/component with individual accounts. The identity pages are SSR.

I have the same issues. Did you find a way?

Same Issue here. I have managed to get as far as putting the Routes.razor into Server with the following Assemblies: ```  private readonly Assembly appAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(_Imports));
private readonly Assembly[] addidionalAssemblies = new[]
{
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Client._Imports))
};``` Then applying rendermode per page with @rendermode ... But something is weird, all other components do not render as described in the page (all components in the Layout and or Routes component still render Server even with WASM defined on page).

You could try use global dynamic render mode, such as following:
...
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage()" />
...
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage()" />
...
@code {
        [CascadingParameter]
        private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;
        //if the page route is "/Counter" ,the rendermode is set to null, equals to SSR
        private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage(){
            if (HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Counter"))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return InteractiveAuto;
            }
        }
}

Then the "counter" button will be ineffective because we dynamically set it to server static mode. But you could then add rendermode to the Counter page, the button will work again with "InteractiveWebAssembly"
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
...


Thank you for your reply. Your suggestion is interesesting. WebAssembly has the Routes.razor  within the client app. I'm presuming you're suggesting to move this to the server. When I do this, the entry application entry point is Sever.Program() and current WebAssembly startup is not invoked.  I'm begining to think what I want is not possible unless 1/ I have separate server/client project for the WebAssembly. 2/Load the Webassembly statically or 3/ Refactor the client so that services can be interchangable between server and client

@dunxz I didn't suggest put Routes in server. Just use use the "blazor web app" template patter and modify the app.razor will work for what I mean.  To be honest, I 'm still confused why you want to <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Sever.Program).Assembly">. Because without this, you can already change to any rendermode  as you like.

hi. thank you for your response. I have taken a good look at the blazor_samples (https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples). Currently my application follows a pattern best described by the sample BlazorSample_WebAssembly and it's behaviour is different from BlazorSample_WebApp. My application relies on local client resources ie local storage, that are not available on the server, and therefore the server cannot prerender any components.  "Just use use the blazor web app template" is quite an ask from where I am at the moment

[...more.] BlazorWebAppCallWebApi_Weather also is close to what I'm doing to get data into the WebAssembly app; using a locally defined service IClient...Serice to populate the app from a server api controller - however in the api sample , the first render is still undertaken by the server. My application is analagous to Vue.js (or similar) with the rendering undertaken by one thing (the WebAssembly) and data served by api.  Sorry for the waffle, I think I'm slowly answering my own queston....not possible
